# How do I add millions of rows to a live production mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

I'm looking to add about 7 million rows to a live production database table that gets 1-2 writes per second. Can I do this without locking the database for writes? I think so because the table uses InnoDB?

Are there other considerations or do I just write the insert statement and let it rip?

Comment: Cant you do it at night?One method is to disable all constraints,try to partially insert the data,WHERE someid < 500000 ,and put it in a transaction to make sure you dont lose data.

Comment: I can do it at night, that's a good idea.

Comment: One confusion about transactions: If I am working on transaction A and a stack of writes B come in, do those writes get processed after I commit my transaction?

Comment: You might get more knowledgeable answers here http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you want to make it snappy, use "load data infile" which is way faster than insert statements.

Comment: I am using [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) to import data into my database that would account to about 5 million rows. It gives an option to export the data from my testing database as an SQL dump and then perform an import in production database. One important feature is, since there are huge number of rows to be copied, SQLyog provides an option to import the data in chunks,therfore avoiding any connection loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB, you don't need to do anything special. 
Just run your inserts. InnoDB uses row level locking for these situations, it will not lock the entire table.

Of course your performance could still take a hit due to the parallel work.

To answer your other question:

"One confusion about transactions: If I am working on transaction A and a stack of writes B come in, do those writes get processed after I commit my transaction"

In general, no. It will not need to wait. This does depend if you are working within the same keyspace or not, and also what isolation level you are working within.